# WinError 2 The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openai-whisper

I am a python newbie and am trying to generate subtitles from mp4 files in python using whisper-timestamped library. I keep getting "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" when I try this code:

```
audio = whisper_timestamped.load_audio(videofile)
```

The weird part is that I tried opening the mp4 file using moviepy to change it to audio just to check if its accessed and it worked fine and the code was able to save the audio file afterwards.

This is the full error code:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 1
----> 1 audio = whisper_timestamped.load_audio("bausenvid.mp4")
      2 model = whisper_timestamped.load_model('base',device='gpu')
      3 results = whisper_timestamped.transcribe(model,audio,language='en')

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\whisper\audio.py:58, in load_audio(file, sr)
     56 # fmt: on
     57 try:
---> 58     out = run(cmd, capture_output=True, check=True).stdout
     59 except CalledProcessError as e:
     60     raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to load audio: {e.stderr.decode()}") from e

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py:501, in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    498     kwargs['stdout'] = PIPE
    499     kwargs['stderr'] = PIPE
--> 501 with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    502     try:
    503         stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py:966, in Popen.__init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask, pipesize)
    962         if self.text_mode:
    963             self.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(self.stderr,
    964                     encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
--> 966     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    967                         pass_fds, cwd, env,
    968                         startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
    969                         p2cread, p2cwrite,
    970                         c2pread, c2pwrite,
    971                         errread, errwrite,
    972                         restore_signals,
    973                         gid, gids, uid, umask,
    974                         start_new_session)
    975 except:
    976     # Cleanup if the child failed starting.
    977     for f in filter(None, (self.stdin, self.stdout, self.stderr)):

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py:1435, in Popen._execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_gid, unused_gids, unused_uid, unused_umask, unused_start_new_session)
   1433 # Start the process
   1434 try:
-> 1435     hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
   1436                              # no special security
   1437                              None, None,
   1438                              int(not close_fds),
   1439                              creationflags,
   1440                              env,
   1441                              cwd,
   1442                              startupinfo)
   1443 finally:
   1444     # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe
   1445     # handles that only the child should have open.  You need
   (...)
   1448     # pipe will not close when the child process exits and the
   1449     # ReadFile will hang.
   1450     self._close_pipe_fds(p2cread, p2cwrite,
   1451                          c2pread, c2pwrite,
   1452                          errread, errwrite)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The online forums suggested including the file directory, I tried that but nothing changed.

Comment: "The online forums suggested including the file directory, I tried that but nothing changed." - **exactly** how did you change the code in order to do this; and exactly what result did you get?

Comment: The error is because it can't find the executable program for audio.  What program is that, and is it on your PATH environment variable?  Are you able to run it at a command prompt?

Comment: Also, why on earth does the error message not say the **actual name** of the program it tried to run?  That's super annoying.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel originally the file is "bausenvid.mp4" and then I changed it to r"G:\shorts automation\bausenvid.mp4".

Comment: @JohnGordon it is on the path environment and apologies about the actual name, I was trying some stuff and I probably didn't change the name back

Comment: but isn't it weird that I was able to generate an audio mp3 file from the mp4 file and straight afterwards it is unable to open in the "whisper_timestamped" command? isn't that irregular?

Comment: "and then I changed it to r"G:\shorts automation\bausenvid.mp4"." - Okay, that's about like I expected, but I had to be sure. I added another duplicate link to cover the issue with that attempt. "but isn't it weird that I was able to generate an audio mp3 file from the mp4 file and straight afterwards it is unable to open in the "whisper_timestamped" command? isn't that irregular?" The problem has nothing to do with the file contents etc. The problem is with how to write Python code that properly explains where the file is.